# Java Script. Арифметическая операция

Tags: javascript

Начала учить JS. 
Подскажите почему в арифметическом скрипте ошибка?

Не выводится...

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var result =  (5 + 7) / ((12 – 5.5) * (5 – 8 * 12)); 
    document.write(result); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что у вас вместо знаков "минус" стоят дефисы.

Так будет работать:

```
var result = (5 + 7) / ((12 - 5.5) * (5 - 8 * 12)); 
document.write(result);
```

Аккуратнее копируйте с книги в следующий раз.

Comment: О, благодарю вас!

Comment: @Anastasia - галочка слева - щёлк :)